# ASP.NET website crash in IE 8 because of mshtml.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer

Recently I am developing a online platform using ASP.NET MVC 3,
and I have received many negative feedback from users about using this platform with IE 8.

I have manage to get the error messages,
but I have no idea what went wrong,
please note the following error message and the generated error report:

AppName: iexplore.exe    AppVer: 8.0.6001.18702  ModName: mshtml.dll
ModVer: 8.0.6001.19170   Offset: 00088fc7

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="iexplore.exe" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="ExtExport.exe" SIZE="144384" CHECKSUM="0xE4CFFC5E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Explorer ImpExp FF exporter" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="extexport.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="extexport" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x2C47C" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:03" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:03" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="hmmapi.dll" SIZE="68608" CHECKSUM="0x3639B01C" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Microsoft HTTP Mail Simple MAPI" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="HMMAPI.DLL" INTERNAL_NAME="HMMAPI" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1713E" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:24:27" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:24:27" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="iecompat.dll" SIZE="6144" CHECKSUM="0xF6FE8860" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.19130" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.19130" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.19130" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Explorer Compatibility Data" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.19130 (longhorn_ie8_gdr.110812-1715)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="iecompat.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="iecompat" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x2B79" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.19130" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.19130" LINK_DATE="08/13/2011 04:43:15" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/13/2011 04:43:15" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="iedvtool.dll" SIZE="743424" CHECKSUM="0x850846EC" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.19165" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.19165" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.19165" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Explorer Developer Tools" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.19165 (longhorn_ie8_gdr.111021-1715)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="iedvtool.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="iedvtool.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xBECF1" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.19165" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.19165" LINK_DATE="11/04/2011 19:20:50" UPTO_LINK_DATE="11/04/2011 19:20:50" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="iedw.exe" SIZE="18432" CHECKSUM="0x655C414" BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="IE Crash Detection" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="iedw.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="iedw.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x13DE4" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5512" LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:34:47" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:34:47" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="ieproxy.dll" SIZE="247808" CHECKSUM="0x4F6039FC" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.19165" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.19165" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.19165" FILE_DESCRIPTION="IE ActiveX Interface Marshaling Library" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.19165 (longhorn_ie8_gdr.111021-1715)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="ieproxy.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="ieproxy.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x440C3" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.19165" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.19165" LINK_DATE="11/04/2011 19:20:53" UPTO_LINK_DATE="11/04/2011 19:20:53" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="iexplore.exe" SIZE="638816" CHECKSUM="0x3532A3B9" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Explorer" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="IEXPLORE.EXE" INTERNAL_NAME="iexplore" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xA0294" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:34:06" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:34:06" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="jsdbgui.dll" SIZE="521216" CHECKSUM="0xB07B9783" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Script Debugger" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="jsdbgui.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="jsdbgui.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x8B81B" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:34:59" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:34:59" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="jsdebuggeride.dll" SIZE="121344" CHECKSUM="0xD614AFBB" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="JScript Debugger IDE" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="jsdebuggeride.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="jsdebuggeride.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x24B51" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:34:58" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:34:58" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="JSProfilerCore.dll" SIZE="118272" CHECKSUM="0x5A1D31D" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="IE Dev Toolbar JScript Profiler" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="JSProfilerCore.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="JSProfilerCore.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x212B0" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:01" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:01" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="jsprofilerui.dll" SIZE="233984" CHECKSUM="0x8DCE4301" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Script Profiler" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="jsprofilerui.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="jsprofilerui.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x42482" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.18702" LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:05" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/08/2009 11:35:05" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="pdm.dll" SIZE="355832" CHECKSUM="0xA49AB6D6" BIN_FILE_VERSION="9.0.30729.1" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="9.0.30729.1" PRODUCT_VERSION="9.0.30729.1" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Process Debug Manager" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2008" FILE_VERSION="9.0.30729.1 built by: SP" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="pdm.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="pdm.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x663E0" LINKER_VERSION="0x90000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="9.0.30729.1" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="9.0.30729.1" LINK_DATE="07/29/2008 14:46:11" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/29/2008 14:46:11" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="sqmapi.dll" SIZE="134144" CHECKSUM="0x8299BD40" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.6000.16386" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.6000.16386" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.6000.16386" FILE_DESCRIPTION="SQM Client" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.0.6000.16386 (vista_rtm.061101-2205)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="sqmapi.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="sqmapi" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x24A81" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.6000.16386" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.6000.16386" LINK_DATE="11/02/2006 09:44:16" UPTO_LINK_DATE="11/02/2006 09:44:16" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="xpshims.dll" SIZE="12800" CHECKSUM="0xC33787D6" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.19165" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.19165" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.19165" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Explorer Compatibility Shims for XP" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.19165 (longhorn_ie8_gdr.111021-1715)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="xpshims.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="xpshims.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xB4D1" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.19165" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.19165" LINK_DATE="11/04/2011 19:20:51" UPTO_LINK_DATE="11/04/2011 19:20:51" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwconn.dll" SIZE="61440" CHECKSUM="0x77064AA7" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="icwconn.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="icwconn" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1974C" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 00:09:46" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 00:09:46" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwconn1.exe" SIZE="214528" CHECKSUM="0x6E57A24F" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="icwconn1.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="icwconn1" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x42D4B" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:35" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:35" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwconn2.exe" SIZE="86016" CHECKSUM="0x2FF8D91" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="ICWCONN2.EXE" INTERNAL_NAME="ICWCONN2" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1AF92" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:39" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:39" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwdl.dll" SIZE="32768" CHECKSUM="0x9B33D57E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Service MIME Mutlipart Download" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="ICWDL.DLL" INTERNAL_NAME="ICWDL" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xEBE5" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 00:09:48" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 00:09:48" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwhelp.dll" SIZE="172032" CHECKSUM="0x40E290E2" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard Helper functions" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="icwhelp.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="icwhelp" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x2FFB4" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 00:09:49" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 00:09:49" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwres.dll" SIZE="61440" CHECKSUM="0xA488AA92" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000 (xpclient.010817-1148)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="icwres.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="icwres" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1AA60" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" LINK_DATE="08/18/2001 05:35:05" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/18/2001 05:35:05" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwrmind.exe" SIZE="24576" CHECKSUM="0xA3F9DFA4" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard Reminder" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="ICWRMIND.EXE" INTERNAL_NAME="ICWRMIND" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xC5E0" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:25" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwtutor.exe" SIZE="73728" CHECKSUM="0xF945F7EB" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000 (xpclient.010817-1148)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="icwtutor.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="icwtutor" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x16B27" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" LINK_DATE="08/17/2001 20:49:08" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/17/2001 20:49:08" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\icwutil.dll" SIZE="49152" CHECKSUM="0x128B2C01" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="icwutil.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="icwutil" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1991A" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 00:09:51" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/14/2008 00:09:51" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\inetwiz.exe" SIZE="20480" CHECKSUM="0xA679099B" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2900.5512 (xpsp.080413-2105)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="INETWIZ.EXE" INTERNAL_NAME="INETWIZ" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x13E7A" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2900.5512" LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:41" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/13/2008 18:31:41" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\isignup.exe" SIZE="16384" CHECKSUM="0xF8AB8D6E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Signup" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000 (xpclient.010817-1148)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="ISIGNUP.EXE" INTERNAL_NAME="ISIGNUP" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x443C" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" LINK_DATE="08/17/2001 20:48:46" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/17/2001 20:48:46" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Connection Wizard\trialoc.dll" SIZE="40960" CHECKSUM="0x68F70073" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Internet Connection Wizard Trial Reminder Helper" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.00.2600.0000 (xpclient.010817-1148)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="trialoc.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="trialoc" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x198FE" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.0.2600.0" LINK_DATE="08/18/2001 05:36:03" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/18/2001 05:36:03" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="MUI\0409\mscorier.dll" SIZE="158720" CHECKSUM="0x5F5BF3DB" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.50727.3053" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.50727.3053" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.50727.3053" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Microsoft .NET Runtime IE resources" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® .NET Framework" FILE_VERSION="2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="mscorier.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="mscorier.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x35132" LINKER_VERSION="0x80000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.50727.3053" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.50727.3053" LINK_DATE="07/25/2008 13:59:33" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/25/2008 13:59:33" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="mshtml.dll" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="mshtml.dll" SIZE="5978112" CHECKSUM="0xD3F35BB2" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.19170" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.19170" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.00.6001.19170" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Microsoft (R) HTML Viewer" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Windows® Internet Explorer" FILE_VERSION="8.00.6001.19170 (longhorn_ie8_gdr.111102-1715)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="MSHTML.DLL" INTERNAL_NAME="MSHTML" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x5BB0DE" LINKER_VERSION="0x60000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.0.6001.19170" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0.6001.19170" LINK_DATE="11/04/2011 19:20:52" UPTO_LINK_DATE="11/04/2011 19:20:52" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="989696" CHECKSUM="0x2D998938" BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781 (xpsp_sp3_gdr.090321-1317)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xFE572" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.5781" LINK_DATE="03/21/2009 14:06:58" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/21/2009 14:06:58" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>
```

So sorry for the lengthy context.
Could anyone help on this issue?
This error has annoyed me during the whole Christmas.

Comment: what was the resolution here? the ie8 patch below seemingly didn't work for you?

Comment: Was there a resolution? I too am getting reports of IE8 (WinXP 5.1 only) users crashing when loading the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing IE9 and an update hotfix of IE9 in your system and try running your application. Also let me know if you are using HTML5 and CSS3 in your application.

And if you dont want to install IE9 and want to continue with the IE8 browser then please install the compatibility patch for mshtml.dll. The download link for patch is http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917425

Comment: The code runs perfectly on IE9. So I expected it is something specific on IE8, and sadly the patch didn't work for me. Luckily all users are agreed to install IE9 now, which is a relieve. I think I better contact Microsoft PSS for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should have nothing at all to do about your site being done with MVC. That is a client side crash, MVC spits out plain html, thats it.

If it crashes on your pages (across your clients) then you've uncovered some interesting IE8  bug with rendering and I would contact Microsoft PSS immediately.

Comment: Yes! I am going to contact Microsoft PSS for this "interesting" bug. Thanks.